# How to show plugin versions

Tags: java, maven

I want to know the version of plugin installed.  Which command can do it?

Comment: The only approach that worked for me was to run the plugin's goal and see the version in the output.

Answer (score 35):

```
mvn -Dplugin=<groupId>:<artifactId> help:describe
```

detailed description of the plugin - including the version

Comment: FWIW: this is not necessarily the version plugin executed in a project build.  If effective-pom is configured differently s.t. the plugin version is different, the version given by `help:describe` and the version used by the build differs.

Answer (score 26):

If you would to know which version of plugins (incl. plugins provided through maven master pom) your build use, try:

```
mvn help:effective-pom
```

Comment: This did not work for me (version 2.2.1-SNAPSHOT not found); however, `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.2:effective-pom` does.

Comment: Yeah, it seems that effective-pom doesn't resolve plugin versions, it include them only if they are configured in parent pom hierarhy.

Answer (score 11):

I don't know what you mean by 'version of plugin *installed*' but the [Maven help plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/) enables you to get the desciption of a plugin by giving the groupId and artifactId,

```
mvn -Dplugin=<groupId>:<artifactId> help:describe
```

You will get a detailed description of the plugin - including the version (although I must admit that I don't know the strategy of version number resolving).

**Example** for the maven-dependency-plugin

```
mvn -Dplugin=org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin help:describe
```

**Output**:

```
Name: Maven Dependency Plugin
Description: Provides utility goals to work with dependencies like copying,
  unpacking, analyzing, resolving and many more.
Group Id: org.apache.maven.plugins
Artifact Id: maven-dependency-plugin
Version: 2.2
Goal Prefix: dependency

This plugin has 21 goals:

dependency:analyze
  Description: Analyzes the dependencies of this project and determines which
    are: used and declared; used and undeclared; unused and declared. This goal
    is intended to be used standalone, thus it always executes the test-compile
    phase - use the dependency:analyze-only goal instead when participating in
    the build lifecycle.

dependency:analyze-dep-mgt
  Description: This mojo looks at the dependencies after final resolution and
    looks for mismatches in your dependencyManagement section. In versions of
    maven prior to 2.0.6, it was possible to inherit versions that didn't match
    your dependencyManagement. See MNG-1577 for more info. This mojo is also
    useful for just detecting projects that override the dependencyManagement
    directly. Set ignoreDirect to false to detect these otherwise normal
    conditions.

dependency:analyze-duplicate
  Description: Analyzes the <dependencies/> and <dependencyManagement/> tags
    in the pom.xml and determines the duplicate declared dependencies.

... and much more
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your `pom.xml` file and you will get the result on `mvn clean install`:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
           <goal>display-dependency-updates</goal>
           <goal>display-plugin-updates</goal>
           <goal>display-property-updates</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

If you just want to do it once:

```
mvn versions:display-plugin-updates
```

Comment: mvn versions:display-plugin-updates downloads the poms of all the plugins in the world. More than I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an "`-X`" parameter when maven is packaged(`mvn clean compile * -X`), and then search for "`artifactId`" to see the exact version number.